# Wrong date format from date & strtotime?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have an irritating problem with date and strtotime.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'));
```

Returns:

```
1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

What am I doing wrong? `1970-01-01 02:00:00` is output correctly `1970-01-01 02:00`, but I am trying to convert a (foreign) formatted date into a timestamp, then output a new date format.

What is the correct way of doing it, if not this way?

**Solved:** The example works, as my problem was an invalid date string (boolean false) which returned 1970-01-01 01:00 (GMT+1). Case closed

Comment: What's your server timezone? `var_dump(strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'));`

Comment: It's GMT +1. Which makes sense for the difference. But not why 1970-01-01 02:00:00 correctly returns 1970-01-01 02:00.

Comment: What's with `var_dump`? What OS you're under? Is it windows?

Comment: Linux, PHP 5.2x. date string(16) "1970-01-01 01:00" strtotime int(0)

Comment: `var_dump(strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'));`, timestamp for the midnight.

Comment: + `var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i', -3600));`

Comment: On your fiddle http://codepad.viper-7.com/w728Af it works well, as it expected

Comment: "Edit: It seems PHP makes a timezone push if the value in strtotime returns 0. Depending on your machine and timezone 1970-01-01 might or might not return 0." --- it always does that. And it is expected. Still waiting for 2 var_dumps

Comment: zerkms: int(-3600) | string(16) "1970-01-01 00:00"

Comment: if `var_dump(strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'));` returns -3600 and `var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i', -3600));` returns `1970-01-01 00:00` then `var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00')));` should return `1970-01-01 00:00` as well. Don't you think so?

Comment: zerkms: So what you are saying is nothing is wrong, and this is the proper way of doing it?

Comment: I'm saying that in the last comment you've shown that everything works as expected. And that the results don't match to the question. In the comment everything works fine, in the question the same code doesn't work. The same code works differently? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're under Windows, that doesn't support negative timestamps for `date`.

So `strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00')` returns negative value and being formatted by `date()` - negative becomes `0`, thus you get an offset equal to your TZ offset.

For `1970-01-01 02:00:00` the result of `strtotime` is `3600` (which is 1 hour + 1 hour from UTC), and this value is positive so it works.

PS: as @Mark Baker pointed out - it was fixed long ago, but it presented in windows version and it's the only explanation for the case

PPS: according to the comments in the question - seems like everything works fine (not sure how OP got the wrong values then)

Comment: I don't have a Windows server demo, but the [codepad](http://codepad.org/K777PHn8) server seems to agree the OP's posted code isn't giving the OPs observed outcome.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: yes I did, and actually I cannot understand it :-(

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you're not native English. The codepad server seems to agree with you (*nix wise).

Comment: Windows has supported negative timestamps in PHP for many years now, you'd have to be running a pretty ancient version of PHP to face that limitation

Comment: @Mark Baker: yep, and that's the only explanation of OP's issue (at least from what I know)